# How to forcefully run a Jar file using 32-bit JVM when both 32-bit and 64-bit JVM are installed?

Tags: java, jar, jvm, 32bit-64bit

How to forcefully run a Jar file using 32-bit JVM when both 32-bit and 64-bit JVMs are installed?

Comment: Depends highly on the JVM - do you use standard Oracle JVM? Which version? And what's your operating system?

Comment: `-d32` may work on some platforms.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try Using [launchj4](http://launch4j.sourceforge.net/) you can wrap your jar into an exe file and specify the JRE you want to use and force it to search for a 32bit JVM, set min and max version etc... The wrapper will automatically search installed JRE's and chose the one that meets the requirements.

Answer (score 1):

Find the java.exe in "C:\Program Files (x86)" and write a cmd-file with one line:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\javasomething\java.exe" -jar "Your 32-Bit-File.jar"
```

Save it as doitso.cmd and doubleclick it.